# Erase RW disc and burn linux .iso

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, burning

How to burn a linux .iso to a RW disc? Btw, the disc has data inside, so I have to erase it and then burn the iso image to the disc

Update: After burning the linux iso I can't mount the cdrom, and the dvd won't boot too on computer start.

If I insert the disc while on OS, the cdrom won't mount. Also if I open gparted it stays "scanning all devices..." forever.

I've also noticed that the were mounted 3 discs or partions after burning the disc.

if i run `sudo mount /dev/sr0` the terminal stays waiting forever

update: it shows this mounted discs or partitions but the cdrom/optical drive can't mount the dvd nor can be detected

[image]

Note: If i remove dvd this partitions stay mounted and accecible

Comment: `brasero` would be a standard GUI-suite that allows you erasing and burning disk.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Brasero](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero) from a terminal window with `sudo apt-get install brasero`

Once installed, launch it, and choose [Burn Imag](https://help.gnome.org/users/brasero/stable/project-image-burn.html.en)e [image: Brasero Main Menu], then select the file with the .ISO file you [verified by checksum comparison](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Select the drive with the RW disc, and tell Brasero to blank (erase) the contents of the disc, then click **Burn** to start writing.

Comment: After burning the linux iso I can't mount the cdrom, and the dvd won't boot too on computer start